# How to create a dynamic drop down within a table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to create a tableview with at least two sections, transportation and hotel. Tapping on either one creates a drop down view showing info on 1 to n examples of the topic selected. You don't know in advance what data is going to be there so it has to be dynamic to present any number of results with some having lengthy descriptions below each example and some not. I've been racking my brain and I can't figure out how to do this. The dynamic nature of this makes it extra difficult. Here is a mock up of what it should look like: [click here](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/journey-production-fbe8f.appspot.com/o/DropDown.png?alt=media&token=7b2bec66-ee0f-43e2-82ac-114dafca1cbc)

Comment: Is there a particular part of this you're struggling with? Is it the data design, working with the UI, or something else?

Comment: It's working with the UI. I don't know how to create a menu with X number of items because they need to be linked to each other in terms of constraints. With a tableview, you have cells that organize differing number of items. I don't know how to create a drop down without knowing its length in advance and the cells that are going to be in it.

Comment: @michaeldebo: based on your picture it looks that you want an expandable `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [this](https://github.com/Archetapp/Drop-Down-Menu) Git-Repo. I am using it inside my app and its working quite well. You can also watch the tutorial for it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22zu-OTS-3M&t=1s

Hope that helps!